# Change my Css animation when port is mobile

Tags: css, animation, mobile, media-queries

i building a website with several css animations.
i got this one class animation that fade the div from the right to left.
i would the use media query to that when the port is mobile the animation goes from left to right..

the animation assigned to div with

```
<div> class="fadeInRight" </div>
```

this is the css for the animation

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {

0%
{
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}

100%
{
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: none;
 transform: none;
}
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
0% 
{
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}

100%
{
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: none;
 transform: none;
}
}

.fadeInRight {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRight;
  animation-name: fadeInRight;
 }
```

and this is what i tried to do..

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {

0%
{
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

100%
{
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: none;
 transform: none;
}
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
0% 
{
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

100%
{
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: none;
 transform: none;
}
}

.fadeInRight {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRight;
  animation-name: fadeInRight;
 }
 }
```

Comment: The code seems to be the same

Comment: i changed the animation and inserted it to media query.